# Xampp localhosting site, how to put site on localhost without subodomain "localhost/home = localhost"

Tags: php, xampp

Can someone help me i am new at this. I dont know how to set my xampp page on localhost without subname
like this localhost/home.
And when i enter localhost it redirects to localhost/dashboard.

Comment: You should configure the Apache configuration file, often called httpd.conf
Check the xampp website where you can find this configuration file.

Comment: A better starting point probably is the documentation of the apache http server itself. Since that is what you are using. Xampp is just a distribution of existing OpenSource packages.